# how to prove that any two circles and any two disks have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1.I am trying to prove that two circles has the same cardinality I declared two intervals 
$[0,2\pi R]$ and $[0,2\pi \widetilde{R}]$ I build I bijection between the two interval 
It's the correct proof ?
$2$.The equation for a closed disk $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}\leqslant R^{2}$.
Can I prove it by doing in the same way that I prove the circles cardinality but now with the area $\pi R^{2}$ instead of using the circumference.
Thanks

Comment: Notice that any continuous curve has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ being an injective image of $[0, 1]$ and also every set containing an open set can be shown to contain a continuous curve and thus has the same cardinality.

Comment: $(1)$. Need to be careful, you want to prove a *geometric* fact. Note want to use half-open intervals, like $[0,2\pi R)$. One cannot assess what you did without being given some detail. $(2)$. Again, need explicit geometric bijection.

Comment: Hello Nicolas:Why did you write half open interval $[0,2\pi R)$ if the point $2\pi R$ is a memeber it is the last point of the circle.

Comment: @Hernan: Circles don't have endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Place the circles so that both of their centres are at origin. Now draw straight lines from origin to the points on the circumference of the bigger circle, which will intersect the circumference of the smaller circle at exactly one point. This will give a bijection between the two circles.

For discs, the map $$f(r,\theta )=(\frac{r R_2}{R_1},\theta)$$
will give a bijection from the disc of radius $R_1$ to the disc of radius $R_2.$

Comment: Thanks, Is my proof for the circles are correct? What is the significance of r?

Comment: Yeah, your proof is also correct, but I found it more easy to visualize. Here $(r,\theta )$ is the polar coordinates of a point in the plane